# Formatting output of a binary search using printf in C?

Tags: c, printf, binary-search

I'm having some trouble with the output of this program. I need to print the verbs on one line, and I need to print a separate statement in the case that there are no verbs. For ex.

`"talk and walk"` should print `"The verbs are: talk walk"`

while `"hello there"` should print `"There are no verbs"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binary_search(char *list_of_words[], int size, char *target){
    int bottom= 0;
    int mid;
    int top = size - 1;
    int found = 0;

    while(bottom <= top && !found){
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) == 0){
            //printf("%s found at location %d.\n", target, mid+1);
            found = 1;
        } else if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) > 0){
            top    = mid - 1;
        } else if (strcmp(list_of_words[mid], target) < 0){
            bottom = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1)
        return mid;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *input = strtok(argv[1], " \"\n");
    char *verbs[5] = { "do", "make", "take", "talk", "walk" };
    int position;
    int check = 0;
    while (input != NULL) {
        //printf("%s\n", input);
        position = binary_search(verbs, 5, input);
        if (position != -1)
            printf("The verbs are: %s\n", verbs[position]);
            check = 1;
        input = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (check == 0){
        printf("There are no verbs\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How can you use binary search to search for a word in a string? Binary search needs the field to be sorted.

Comment: Instead of printing `printf("The verbs are: %s\n", verbs[position]);`, store `verbs[position]` into an array and print after the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be working fine, but you need to add parenthesis around

```
    if (position != -1)
        printf("The verbs are: %s\n", verbs[position]);
        check = 1;
```

like in

```
    if (position != -1) {
        printf("The verbs are: %s\n", verbs[position]);
        check = 1;
    }
```

otherwise check is always set 1 in the loop.

And if you do not want to repeat "The verbs are:" , add a check for that

```
    if (position != -1) {
        if (first) {
            printf("The verbs are:");
            first = 0;
            check = 1;
        }
        printf(" %s", verbs[position]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *input = strtok(argv[1], " \"\n");
    char *verbs[5] = { "do", "make", "take", "talk", "walk" };
    char match[5] = {0};
    int position;
    int check = 0;
    while (input != NULL) {
        //printf("%s\n", input);
        position = binary_search(verbs, 5, input);
        if (position != -1){
            //printf("The verbs are: %s\n", verbs[position]);
            match[position]=1;//match[position] = check = 1;
            check = 1;
        }
        input = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (check == 0){
        printf("There are no verbs\n");
    } else {
        int i;
        printf("The verbs are: ");
        for(i=0;i<5;++i)
            if(match[i])
                printf("%s ", verbs[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're more interested in just having the search done, rather than implementing it yourself (i.e., assuming "implement a search" is not your actual task), you should use the standard library's little-known hero, [`bsearch()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch).

Note that this requires the input data (the array you're searching in) to be sorted, but yours seems to be since you're already working on a binary search.